# Excel INDEX MATCH multi-column dataset into row-column dataset

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have the following dataset:

```
ID  DATE    MEAN
2774    13174   0.674203033
2774    13234   0.24248537
2774    13324   0.577691487
2774    13344   0.566831396
2774    13384   0.30762495
2774    13404   0.284883448
2774    13444   0.096585341
2774    13484   0.489822992
2774    13514   0.001782501
2775    13284   0.358919173
2775    13324   0.59444239
2775    13344   0.496785916
2775    13364   0.41113428
2775    13384   0.482818723
2775    13444   0.061972905
2775    13464   0.245064925
2775    13484   0.539972425
2776    13174   0.254853256
2776    13234   0.288461709
2776    13284   0.23615498
2776    13304   0.086730293
2776    13324   0.283138381
2776    13344   0.262207605
2776    13364   0.252859662
2776    13384   0.268640347
```

I want to reformat it in Excel into this format where date is the horizontal header and ID is the vertical header:

```
ID  13174   13234   13284   13304   13324   13344   13364   13384   13404   13444   13464   13484   13514
2774                                                    
2775                                                    
2776
```

I know I need to use INDEX and MATCH and this is what I came up with but for some reason it's not working. It gives me #N/A

```
=INDEX($A$2:$C$25,MATCH(1,($F3=$A$2:$A$25)*(G$1=$B$2:$B$25),0),3)
```

I also tried using SUMPRODUCT but that gave me a #VALUE!

```
=INDEX(C2:C847051,SUMPRODUCT((A2:A847051=E2)*(B2:B847051=G1)*ROW(2:847051))-1)
```

Btw, this is a simplified dataset just for the purpose of asking this question. My real dataset has nearly 30k unique IDs and 48 unique dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMIF:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$F3,$B:$B,G$1)
```

But ultimately a Pivot Table will do this automatically.

[image]

Comment: Both solutions work but the SUMIF formula will bog your computer down if you have a huge dataset. Mine crashed twice so I went with the Pivot table.